# Handle request headers in IHS (ibm http server)

Tags: apache, ibmhttpserver

I have some configuration like :

Listen 9000
<VirtualHost *: 9000>
.....
ProxyPass .....
ProxyPassReverse ....

it works well.
But I faced with problem. We have healthCheck (GET /health http1.1) and this is request does not have "Host" header and before that this check had called to Liberty directly. Now we use IHS like proxy.

All requests without this headers are declined(access error).
Do I have any option how to handle it ?
I tried to set this header
RequestHeader set "Host" "example"

But any way I get error

My second qustion is why this set up works just within the virtualhost?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/1.1 protocol requires a host header. The health check software should be corrected to include host header or use HTTP/1.0 which does not require Host header. RFC2616 section 14.23 "A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages."

Comment: If it is required how does the liberty work without ? Maybe IHS has some mechanism to handle that?

Comment: Sounds like Liberty isn't RFC compliant.